# Civil 3d TIN object in Forge viewer to return elevation?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

Just trying to find the document to prove an idea. Is there a viewer api to return the elevation of a surface from an xy input? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, the viewer does not expose any of the Civil3d API. It only extracts properties from objects. So unless that property is extracted, there is no way to compute it from the viewer. Only Design Automation for Civil3d will give you that ability. Checkout this [blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-civil-3d-public-beta).